# Simple jQuery .size() and .length() 'not a function' error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: $(this).find('.btn-default').size is not a function. (In '$(this).find('.btn-default').size()', '$(this).find('.btn-default').size' is undefined)
```

As a result of this code:

```
console.log($(this).find('.btn-default').size());
```

I get the same error if I use `.length()` instead.  I am using jQuery 3.3.1.  [This working example](https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/K9vhhTmYde) is using jQuery 3.1.1 with `size()`.  I'm sure I'm doing something incredibly simple but wrong, but I cannot find the problem.

EDIT:  Once again, the problem was my bad eyesight.  The answer is:  `length` is a property, not a function.

Who knows why the `codeply` example claims to be using jQuery 3.1.1. with `size()` but clearly that should not be possible, according to comments below.

Comment: `size()` is depreciated as of jQuery v1.8 and `length` does not accept parameters, so it would just be `.length`. See [`size()`](https://api.jquery.com/size/) and [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/)

Comment: Your example is using jQuery 1.9.1, not 3.3.1 as you claim

Comment: Why exactly are you using .size() and .length()?

Comment: `console.log($(this).find('.btn').length);` fails the same way.

Comment: @KevinB - I tried using .size() because it was in the codeply example.  I tried .length() because .size() is deprecated.

Comment: In my haste to respond to all of your comments, I misread the console error messages a bit:  `.length` did not fail, but rather a later call to `.length()` leftover from my experiments failed.  Answer below is correct.  I needed to use a property, not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the size is deprected since 1.8 and removed in 3.0 see here [size()](https://api.jquery.com/size/)

Use `$(this).find('.btn-default').length` (property not function ) instead

Comment: "property not function" is the key.  I misread the docs, and then further misread my debug output on the console, and got mislead.

Comment: @CXJ I'm glad you fixed your issue :)